# Are browser tests needed?

Tags: laravel, testing, laravel-dusk

Why would someone need to do browser tests ( using tools like Laravel dusk ),
when they already doing "Feature tests" and "Unit tests"?

Is browser tests needed for the app? and why?

Answer (score 0):

For testing there's different approaches which yield different results. In order to answer your question I'll list them below and then circle back to the answer.

## Unit testing

- These are used for testing very small parts of your application.
- A 'unit' is a single class, not a combination of classes.
- When unit testing any interaction with other classes is usually mocked so only the 'unit' itself is tested.
- Unit test are very fast to execute
- Due to unit tests being fast it's often used for testing all paths (e.g. happy path, alternative path and exception paths)
- Usually done in phpunit
- Does not have database interaction

## Integration testing

- These are used for testing the interaction between different units
- Only a few paths should be tested, as the amount of paths increases a lot when involving more units (e.g. class A has 3 paths, class B has 4 paths so an 100% coverage in integration tests should cover 12 paths)
- Still quite fast
- Usually done in phpunit
- Can have database interaction

## Feature testing

- These are used for testing one single feature
- Usually just the happy path (maybe one other path) is tested
- Usually has database interaction
- Quite slow
- Can have a few of these, but not too many
- Usually done in Behat

## Browser testing

- These are used for testing a feature from start to end
- Simulates how an actual user would be visiting your application
- Can be used for checking if a feature works across different browsers
- Depending on tooling can record videos of the actual mouse movements / keyboard strokes
- Very slow
- Only a select few should be used
- Usually done in Dusk (for Laravel)

## Conclusion

To conclude levels of testing have different usages related to test speed, test coverage and size of code under test. As for feature testing vs browser testing the difference would be in the actual simulation of users interaction with your application versus a machine doing all the work, to check compatibility across different browsers and checking if a feature works from end to end.